# RegEx to capture text after final instance of pattern found

Tags: regex

I would like to use a regular expression to grab a section of text that I know will always follow a series of four digits followed by a space and then a dash and then another space. I would like to capture the text that occurs after the final instance of this pattern to the end of the line.

For example

```
2222-6453-ABC-1234 - The text I want to capture
ABCD - 7654 - The text I want to capture
7GF2-0000 - ABC - 4444 - The text I want to capture
87628734878764-0631 - The text I want to capture
ab2d6m2k6 -9867 - The text I want to capture
```

In the example above the only consistent pattern I can rely on is that there will be a group of four digits followed by a space, a dash, and then another space preceding the text I want to capture. If there are multiple instances of the four digits space dash space pattern the text I want to capture will be after the final instance of the pattern.

The regex pattern is

```
(\d\d\d\d - )
```

but how do I specify that I want to start capturing text after the **final** instance of the pattern?

Comment: what if the text you want to capture also contains 4-digit number? `2222-6453-ABC-1234 - The text I want to - 1111 capture`

Comment: Good point, it It could contain the pattern itself.

Comment: I suspect you may just use [`.*\b\d{4}\s*-\s*(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZGH10Q/1) and grab Group 1 value. What is your programming environment?

Comment: Using .NET. regex library. I used @Thm Lee's answer and just used the single match.

Comment: How about a reason for the downvote to the question and the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
(?m)(?<=\d{4}\s-\s)(?:(?!\d{4}\s-\s)[^\n])*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/156)

Comment: That captures also captures `ABC - 4444 - ` in the third example

Comment: Sorry I missed that point. Just now I fixed my answer. Please retry it again. thank you:-)